# New table not displaying in rails_admin after created using rails g scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm new to RoR and have only done light scripting and VB, so I'm sorry for the lack of knowledge.

I have used the Rails_admin gem to add the admin feature to my ruby app.  I then use rails to generate scaffold. Ran rake to bring my db to the latest version. It creates the new table which I can access through `http://localhost:3000/phonenumbers` , but when I go to the `http://localhost:3000/admin` only my Users table is displayed.  Does rails_admin not automatically recognize all tables in the database?

Comment: Did you do `rake db:migrate` and restart rails server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your server?

I experienced a similar problem trying to add a new table, and rails admin on the same table, in one deploy. This was because rails admin initializes routes for a table but the migration had not run yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was so focused on my migration that i forgot to add the model.  You have to restart the rails app so Rails_Admin will pick up the new model.  It uses the model to derive the structure not the database.